# Google Places API search results refresh on Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm trying to use the Places and Maps API on iOS to search for places within a given radius and filtered by type also with a keyword.

I already implemented the places search to get the locations result by the filter options. That's ok.
Now I have to place these locations as a marker on the map and here comes the question.

If I move/zoom the map, the marker list needs to be updated based on the coordinates/viewport. What is the best practice to fetch the data with places api?
The places api's search shows only 20 results and you have to call again with next_page_token, to get the full result list.
Obviously that's not the most effective and elegant way to update the map markers when moving...

Sorry if it's a n00b question, I used Google Maps API long time ago, when there was no restriction on the search result number...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/events

You will want to implement the `GMSMapViewDelegate` protocol in your ViewController so you can listen for Camera Position events. The best practice would be to wait until moving the map has stopped by listening for the `mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:` event. That way, you do not make too many unnecessary searches or re-drawing of the markers which can slow performance. Sample code at:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/events#camera_position